# Template for documenting Architecture alternatives and decisions

Tags: architecture

We are putting a process in place where all architecture changes must be documented.

Are there any standard templates for documenting alternatives and decisions?

Comment: Available templates are discussed at https://www.ifs.hsr.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/ifs.hsr.ch/Home/projekte/ADMentor-WICSA2015ubmissionv11nc.pdf. We started a discussion on them at https://github.com/adr/madr/issues/8.

Comment: Markdown-based templates are collected at https://github.com/joelparkerhenderson/architecture_decision_record by @joelparkerhenderson (https://stackoverflow.com/users/528726/joelparkerhenderson)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends on how detailed / formal you want to be. In terms of a Decisions Register we'd normally use one doc per area / decision, although recently we've been experimenting with OneNote.

At the very least you want to record (for each option):

- Option Description
- Pros and Cons
- Risks and Issues
- Assumptions and Constraints
- Points of Note

A succinct bullet-point list of pros & cons (etc) is usually sufficient - it doesn't need to be a big doc.

For a more in-depth / formal / complex scenario you'd want to go further, this is the format we were using in such cases:

**Summary**

- Problem Definition
- Solution Context
- Assumptions
- Constraints

**Evaluation Criteria**

(This is important as it sets out the criteria you used to score the available options, including weightings etc).

**Summary of Recommendations**

- Summary
- High-Level Comparison Table  (This is good for providing an "at a glance" comparison for people who don't want to read a long document; and having a side-by-side comparison is a good idea anyway).

**[Option 1…N]**

- Option Description
- Pros and Cons
- Risks and Issues
- Assumptions and Constraints
- Points of Note

**Recommendation**

Answer (score 6):

We collect information regarding architectural decision records at https://adr.github.io/.

### MADR - The Markdown Architecture Decision Records

[MADR](https://github.com/adr/madr) establishes an easy markdown format for  architectural decisions.

The template reads as follows:

```markdown
# {short title of solved problem and solution}

## Context and Problem Statement

{Describe the context and problem statement, e.g., in free form using two to three sentences or in the form of an illustrative story.
 You may want to articulate the problem in form of a question and add links to collaboration boards or issue management systems.}

<!-- This is an optional element. Feel free to remove. -->
## Decision Drivers

* {decision driver 1, e.g., a force, facing concern, …}
* {decision driver 2, e.g., a force, facing concern, …}
* … <!-- numbers of drivers can vary -->

## Considered Options

* {title of option 1}
* {title of option 2}
* {title of option 3}
* … <!-- numbers of options can vary -->

## Decision Outcome

Chosen option: "{title of option 1}", because
{justification. e.g., only option, which meets k.o. criterion decision driver | which resolves force {force} | … | comes out best (see below)}.

<!-- This is an optional element. Feel free to remove. -->
### Positive Consequences

* {e.g., improvement of one or more desired qualities, …}
* …

<!-- This is an optional element. Feel free to remove. -->
### Negative Consequences

* {e.g., compromising one or more desired qualities, …}
* …

<!-- This is an optional element. Feel free to remove. -->
## Validation

{describe how the implementation of/compliance with the ADR is validated. E.g., by a review or an ArchUnit test}

<!-- This is an optional element. Feel free to remove. -->
## Pros and Cons of the Options

### {title of option 1}

<!-- This is an optional element. Feel free to remove. -->
{example | description | pointer to more information | …}

* Good, because {argument a}
* Good, because {argument b}
<!-- use "neutral" if the given argument weights neither for good nor bad -->
* Neutral, because {argument c}
* Bad, because {argument d}
* … <!-- numbers of pros and cons can vary -->

### {title of other option}

{example | description | pointer to more information | …}

* Good, because {argument a}
* Good, because {argument b}
* Neutral, because {argument c}
* Bad, because {argument d}
* …

<!-- This is an optional element. Feel free to remove. -->
## More Information

{You might want to provide additional evidence/confidence for the decision outcome here and/or
 document the team agreement on the decision and/or
 define when this decision when and how the decision should be realized and if/when it should be re-visited and/or
 how the decision is validated.
 Links to other decisions and resources might here appear as well.}
```

The template is available at https://github.com/adr/madr/blob/main/template/adr-template.md.

### Sustainable Architectural Decision

The blog post [Sustainable Architectural Design Decisions](https://www.infoq.com/articles/sustainable-architectural-design-decisions) proposes following text:

> In the context of `<use case/user story u>`, facing `<concern c>` we decided for `<option o>` to achieve `<quality q>`, accepting `<downside d>`.

In some projects, we use the following extension:

> In the context of `<use case/user story u>`,
> facing `<concern c>`
> we decided for `<option o>`
> and neglected `<other options>`,
> to achieve `<system qualities/desired consequences>`,
> accepting `<downside d/undesired consequences>`,
> because `<additional rationale>`.

### Other Solutions

Other solutions, including markdown templates, are listed at https://adr.github.io/.

Answer (score 3):

[github:npryce/adr-tools](https://github.com/npryce/adr-tools) uses this [simple template](https://github.com/npryce/adr-tools/blob/master/src/template.md)

- Title
- - Date
- Status
- Context
- Decision
- Consequences

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you use a specific architecture framework - most of them come with some sort of templates. If you don't use any, I would recommend the [SPAMMED Architecture Framework](http://arnon.me/spammed-architecture-framework-saf/) - it is extremely lightweight. Even if you won't find this framework usable, you can still benefit from the templates it provides.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy even with **mind-mapping** accompanied with a detailed documents when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we have found that using the following format works well for us:

- **Context** (What is the issue we're seeing that is motivating this decision or change)
- **Decision** (What is the change that we're actually doing)
- **Consequences** (What becomes easier or more difficult to do because of this change)

It is similar to how we structure our tests:

*given a scenario, when I do X, I expect Y to be the result*,

so I think that makes it more natural for us to write and read. YMMV.

Blog post of Michael Nygard doing something similar: http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2011/11/15/documenting-architecture-decisions

Comment: There is the tool [adr-tools](https://github.com/npryce/adr-tools), which offers management of these architectural decisions in a source code repository.